# The comment pop-up is too far away

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, design

When you click the `add a comment` button when you don't have enough rep, you get a pop-up saying that you need more rep in able to comment. Except, it is too far away and users might be confused for a while before realizing the pop-up is on the other side of the page:

[image]

Clearly, that is very inconvenient for a lot of people, like me. Can we move the pop-up to be right next to the `add a comment` button?

Comment: freehand circles ftw!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reporting!

Fixed and deployed.